# Determine age from stored date of births

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've only seen SQL calculated ages from DOBs that are passed as parameters. How would I go about doing this from already stored DOBs as `date` type?

I thought this would work but it returns no rows despite having DOBs from 2000 - 2006

```
Select DateDiff(YEAR, dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as ageYears
from users
```

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause so that query should return as many rows as there are rows in `users`. If you're getting no rows, then the only explanation I can think of is that `users` is empty.

Comment: Aha, I wasn't referring to the correct table. I have multiple databases with the same table names! Doh

Comment: @Lee Damien's answer is OK. If you get no rows you have a problem elsewhere, not in the logic calculating the age (the correct count of years elapsed).

Comment: To confirm - are you running, in a single query window, two queries - the above, and a plain `select * from users`, and one is returning a different number of rows than the other?

Comment: No I just left out the `[db].[dbo]` and went straight to `[table]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age in years is slightly complicated because `DATEDIFF` counts boundary transitions (new years eve -> new years day)<sup>1</sup>.

This should give correct answers:

```
Select DateDiff(YEAR, dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 
  CASE WHEN
        DATEADD(year,DateDiff(YEAR, dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END as ageYears
from users
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Which would mean that the simpler `DateDiff(YEAR, dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` will give an answer of 1 for someone born on 31st December 2013, for a query running on 1st January 2014. Which most people think is an incorrect answer for the age in years.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I noticed I have that bug which you later on explained about.

Comment: I would maybe just change CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to GetDate() to be standards compliant.

Comment: @peter.petrov - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` **is** the SQL standard one `GetDate()` is SQL Server dialect. (Not that it matters that much since `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` are also dialect)